# Найти среднее по столбцу с условием

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Нужно создать столбец, который содержит среднее элементов другого столбца.

```
                  Sector    Year    FIRM    Sales   Sales_3 g_firm   
3   Information Technology  2003    1013    773.2   3287.9  -0.254945
4   Information Technology  2004    1013    784.3   2402.8  -0.224530
5   Information Technology  2005    1013    1169.2  1047.7  0.038656
6   Industry                2006    1013    1281.9  773.2   0.219305
7   Industry                2007    1013    1322.2  784.3   0.228612
```

Есть столбец 'g_firm'. Нужно найти среднее по этому столбцу и записать это значение в каждую ячейку столбца 'g_firm_1'. При этом среднее нужно находить с учетом значений 'Sector'. Для каждого сектора будет свое среднее значение 'g_firm'

Итоговая таблица должна выглядеть так

```
                  Sector    Year    FIRM    Sales   Sales_3  g_firm   g_firm_1
3   Information Technology  2003    1013    773.2   3287.9  -0.254945  -0.1469
4   Information Technology  2004    1013    784.3   2402.8  -0.224530  -0.1469
5   Information Technology  2005    1013    1169.2  1047.7  0.038656   -0.1469
6   Industry                2006    1013    1281.9  773.2   0.219305   0.2238
7   Industry                2007    1013    1322.2  784.3   0.228612   0.2238
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [Series.transform()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.transform.html):

```
In [5]: df["g_firm_1"] = df.groupby("Sector")["g_firm"].transform("mean")
```

результат:

```
In [6]: df
Out[6]:
                   Sector  Year  FIRM   Sales  Sales_3    g_firm  g_firm_1
0  Information Technology  2003  1013   773.2   3287.9 -0.254945 -0.146940
1  Information Technology  2004  1013   784.3   2402.8 -0.224530 -0.146940
2  Information Technology  2005  1013  1169.2   1047.7  0.038656 -0.146940
3                Industry  2006  1013  1281.9    773.2  0.219305  0.223959
4                Industry  2007  1013  1322.2    784.3  0.228612  0.223959
```